# plug icon is missing with default org name in vscode

Tags: salesforcedx, vs-code

As per the documentation "[Change or Open Your Default Org](https://forcedotcom.github.io/salesforcedx-vscode/articles/user-guide/default-org)", In vscode, I should see plug icon with the default org name but it disappeared from last few days.

Here is the screenshot(stolen from this [tweet](https://twitter.com/ch_sz_knapp/status/1095600887094018048)) showing the plug icon I am talking about:

[image]

I see the browser icon but not the plug icon.

Here is the screenshot showing that I indeed have a default org configured when I ran the command without changing folder in vscode:

[image]

Has anyone noticed this disappearance of the plug icon lately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed the same .Once you set the default scratch org or default org (sandbox or dev org) then reload the window of the vscode .

You can reload it using command pallete . Find the reload window command as shown below

[image]

Note that you will need to use `sfdx force:config:list` to double check if you have the defaultusername set for the project workspace

[image]

Comment: `sfdx force:config:list` shows defaultusername set to my sandbox but it still not showing the plug icon. I reloaded the window also. Maybe it will show the plug icon only if the default org is a scratch org and not for Sandboxes?

Comment: I have it for the sandbox only .I have authorized a sandbox

Comment: whats your operating system ?

Comment: Ubuntu. It shows browser icon though and clicking on it is opening my sandbox org in the browser successfully.

Comment: I think next step is to report it on the git repo as issue with your os .Surprising it shows fine for me .Do you have dev hub for the org enabled ?

Comment: Or a default devhub set ?

Comment: No, I don't. I just have "defaultusername" configured. I reloaded the window multiple times and it showed up once and then disappeared. Not sure what is going on and thanks for your answer though.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, enabling the Salesforce CLI solved that problem.

[image]